# Problem getting SD from a 95% CI of a probability

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval, simulation

I'm working on a simulation designed to investigate fertility, birth control, etc.  One of the inputs to the simulation is the probability that a given ovulatory cycle is capable of producing a pregnancy, termed *cycle viability*.  Being a Monte Carlo simulation, I need to be able to generate random samples from the distribution of cycle viabilities.  (So, to be clear, the distribution function yields the probability of a probability!)

Cycle viability is estimated in a [1995 paper from Weinberg et al.](https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJM199512073332301?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) as 0.37, which is given with a 95% confidence interval of [0.31, 0.48].  There were 221 women and 625 cycles included in the analysis.

My understanding of confidence intervals is only rather informal and rough.  The first thing that caught my attention was that *the mean is not in the center of the confidence interval*.  Does this mean that the distribution is not Gaussian?  If not, what would be a reasonable distribution for me to sample from?

I found [instructions](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_3_2_obtaining_standard_deviations_from_standard_errors_and.htm) for obtaining the standard deviation from the 95% C.I., as follows:

$\sigma = \sqrt{N}\ \cdot\ \frac{upper\_limit\ -\ lower\_limit}{3.92}$

I'm assuming N=221 and not N=625, because you can't get a probability from a single event and furthermore the latter produces an unrealistically high SD.

That gives me SD=0.6447, but this is problematic because it implies a 1SD range of [-0.2747, 1.0147], but the variable under investigation, itself a probability, would be nonsensical outside of the [0,1] range.

I could just clamp my samples to [0,1], and I would be comfortable to do so if the 2SD range was *close* to fitting within [0,1], but with the 1SD range's lower bound already being 27% outside of the logical range, I'm afraid 0 would be grossly over-represented in the sample.

Where am I going wrong here and what would I have to do to generate reasonable random samples of cycle viability (i.e., what would be a reasonable PDF and how would I find reasonable parameters from the information available)?

Comment: The asymmetry of the CI reflects the *procedure* used to compute it.  The underlying distribution might or might not be Gaussian or symmetric (but likely is neither).  The very best way to answer your question is to search the paper closely for clues about what procedure was used.  Such clues might include hints about the implicit statistical model.  BTW, there's nothing wrong or even unusual about a one SD deviation from the mean extending to impossible values of the data.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the tips!  The paper didn't say much but linked one that did.  "Cycle viability" is a latent variable in a model solved by EM.  Though in reality it would show subject variability, they discount this and treat it as fixed.  Seems the CI is probably from likelihood ratios from including or excluding the variable from the model.  From that the CI looks probably meaningless for my purposes; ie, if I understand their process correctly, I don't think it reflects the population distribution in any meaningful way.  I'll probably just treat it as a fixed parameter.